# Problems with Formview showing details of Gridview selected row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms, formview

I am trying to have a user select a row in this grid view and have a set of details about that entry display in a formview. Currently, I am getting the error "Invalid column name 's.SprayId' ". I have encountered several issues with this and am out of ideas. I have posted my code below. Any ideas on how to fix this or a better way to do it? Thanks.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvHistory" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsHistory" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="SprayId">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999"></EditRowStyle>

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>

    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>

    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White"></PagerStyle>

    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333"></RowStyle>

    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333"></SelectedRowStyle>

    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>

    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>

    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>

    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsHistory" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:WSFConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [SprayId], [Date], [TimeStart] FROM [Spray] WHERE ([Date] >= (GETDATE() - 7)) ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [TimeStart] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:FormView ID="fvHistoryDetail" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" DataSourceID="dsHistoryDetail" DataKeyNames="SprayId">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        SprayId:
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("SprayId") %>' runat="server" ID="SprayIdLabel1" /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" ID="UpdateButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ID="UpdateCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
    </EditItemTemplate>

    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999"></EditRowStyle>

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>

    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>

    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" ID="InsertButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ID="InsertCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        SprayId:
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("SprayId") %>' runat="server" ID="SprayIdLabel" /><br />

    </ItemTemplate>

    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White"></PagerStyle>

    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333"></RowStyle>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsHistoryDetail" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:WSFConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT s.SprayId as 'ID', [Date], TimeStart as 'Time Start', StartLocationDescription as 'Start', EndLocationDescription as 'End', v.VehicleNumber, (a.FirstName + a.LastName) as 'Applicator', c.TradeName as 'Chemical' FROM Spray s join Vehicle v on s.VehicleId = v.VehicleId join Applicator a on s.Applicator1Id = a.ApplicatorId join SprayChemicalsUsed scu on scu.SprayId = s.SprayId join ChemicalsUsed cu on scu.ChemUsedId = cu.ChemUsedId join Chemical c on cu.ChemId = c.ChemId WHERE ([s.SprayId] = @SprayId)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvHistory" PropertyName="SelectedValue" DefaultValue="1" Name="SprayId" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your select command query:

```
SELECT s.SprayId as 'ID', [Date], TimeStart as 'Time Start', StartLocationDescription as 'Start', EndLocationDescription as 'End', v.VehicleNumber, (a.FirstName + a.LastName) as 'Applicator', c.TradeName as 'Chemical' FROM Spray s join Vehicle v on s.VehicleId = v.VehicleId join Applicator a on s.Applicator1Id = a.ApplicatorId join SprayChemicalsUsed scu on scu.SprayId = s.SprayId join ChemicalsUsed cu on scu.ChemUsedId = cu.ChemUsedId join Chemical c on cu.ChemId = c.ChemId WHERE ([s.SprayId] = @SprayId)
```

Does the column exist and is the name correct would be the first thing to check.

I would open this up in SQL management query or whatever database tool you are using and get it working in there first. It should be quite apparent what the issue is as the GUI will highlight errors in your SQL syntax.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this. I wrote that query in SQL Management  Studio and there are no syntactical issues. However, it is not returning the desired data. I am instead getting each of the column headers returned without any data in them.

Comment: I just noticed that the form fvHistoryDetail data source of dsHistoryDetail is aliasing the SprayId column as ID and you have Evals for "SprayId" in that form

Comment: This is true but removing or changing the alias seems to have no effect on the problem at hand.

Comment: Have you checked your connection string in the project against the database you are connecting to in SQLMS? Also is it possible there is another table of the same name which is missing this SprayId column?

Comment: The error message you are getting implies the issue is with the data, not the gridview.